# Gradle build failed in android studio using react native

Tags: react-native, android-studio

is anyone know how to fix this error?

> D:\Projects\Mobile Projects\React
>   Native\catholicconnect\node_modules\react-native-version-number\android\src\main\java\com\apsl\versionnumber\RNVersionNumberModule.java:
>   uses or overrides a deprecated API. Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation
>   for details.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kGURK.png)

Comment: Do you use React-Native with Expo?

Comment: No @Abdessamad. Just React Native